# Swift - UIDatePicker gets squished when using inline style

Tags: swift, xcode, uidatepicker

I'm facing a problem that my UIDatePicker get squished when using inline style.

[image]

Code:

```
func creatDatePicker() {
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
        toolbar.setItems([doneBtn], animated: true)
        expiryDateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        expiryDateTextField.inputView = datePicker
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
    }
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not supposed to use the new `.inline` styles, when using a `UIDatePicker` as an inputView.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652943)

> You should no longer use a date picker as input view if you are using the new styles - Posted 1 year ago by Frameworks Engineer 

The alternatives I see are as follows.

1. Revert back to the `.wheels` style.
2. If your App's iOS Deployment Target is 14.0 or higher, you can use a `UIDatePicker` in-place of the current `UITextField`. It would look something as shown in the screenshot below (Figure A).

**Figure A**

[image: iOS Picker with .compact (default) style]